# Quickest way to check that a value in PHP only contains digits?

Tags: php, webforms

I could do this the painful way with a double for loop, but surely there's an inbuilt method? Will be used to validate phone number entries.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[ctype_digit()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.ctype-digit.php)

Answer (score 0):

```
preg_match('/^\d+$/', $string);
```

Checks to see if the whole string is just digits.

If you want to match spaces as well:

```
preg_match('/^[0-9 ]+$/', $string);
```

Comment: Does it work well with whitespace? If not, just `trim()` the input.

Comment: @Blender no, but it could be adapted as such

Comment: @Marty it's rather simple, really. `/` means start of regexp, `^` means match the start of the string, `\d+` means match one or more digits, `$` means match the end of the string, and `/` means end of regexp.

Comment: Thanks for the run-down, still very vague. I shall look into regexp some more :)

Comment: @Marty it's definitely a must for any hacker.

Comment: @galymzhan how is that any different from what I wrote?