# how to check if PHP variable contains non-numbers?

Tags: php, string, forms, variables

I just want to know the method to check a PHP variable for any non-numbers and if it also detects spaces between characters? Need to make sure nothing weird gets put into my form fields. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Could you provide a bit more detail? Examples of acceptable and unacceptable values?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5740371/quickest-way-to-check-that-a-value-in-php-only-contains-digits

Comment: please use the search function before asking. this has been asked numerous times before.

Comment: Could you be more precise: do you want to make sure the user enter a **numerical value**, or do you want **only digits**? There is a difference.

Answer (score 41, accepted):

If you mean that you only want a value to contain digits then you can use [`ctype_digit()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.ctype-digit.php).

Comment: This should be rewritten as, “ […] you only want a value to contain **digits** then you can use `ctype_digit()`”. That function will fail on `1.25` or `-11` which are “numbers”. If the OP wants to check if a value contains a number they should use `is_numeric()`.

Comment: Be aware `ctype_digit` returns false if you pass it an integer, so if you're using this function to, for example, validate input, then you may want to allow for integers (e.g. from JSON input). You could still use `ctype_digit`, but cast the input to a string first.

Answer (score 32):

You can use [`is_numeric()`](http://php.net/manual/fr/function.is-numeric.php) :

```
if ( is_numeric($_POST['foo']) ) {
    $foo = $_POST['foo'];
} else {
    // Error
}
```

This will check that the value is numerical, so it may contain something else than digits:

```
12
-12
12.1
```

But this will ensure that the value is a **valid number**.

Comment: This has advantages over `ctype_digit()` in that it allows decimals and negatives.

Comment: `is_numeric()` returns `true` for any numeric value, i.e., it may contain also other characters as long as they describe a number. Possible valid values for `is_numeric()` are: "-1337", "13.37", "13e37", "0x1337". As you can see, they contain non-number characters.

Comment: @mjec, in addition to decimals and negatives, it also allows "positives" (i.e., with "+" sign), exponentials (with "e" letter) and hexidecimals (starting with "0x").

Comment: @binaryLV yes this is why `is_numeric()` is a better choice to validate the numerical input of the user in a form.

Comment: @Matthieu This won't be a good option assuming that **only numeric characters** are allowed (which I've gathered from the question).

Comment: @Matthieu, I'd say it is worse rather than better. There's no point in allowing user to input "0x55" as a numeric value. As an addition, while such value would be valid for converting to integer in PHP, it is not valid in some databases (e.g., MySQL).

Answer (score 19):

You can use [`ctype_digit`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.ctype-digit.php)

eg:

```
if (!ctype_digit($myString)) {
    echo "Contains non-numbers.";
}
```

Comment: `ctype_digit(1)` will return **false**, `ctype_digit("-1.5")` too, so it's better to use `is_numeric()` to handle all variable types.

Comment: @Matthieu, it is not *better*, it is *different*.

Comment: @binaryLV it is *better* for this use case, of course I'm not talking in general...

Comment: @Matthieu, "this use case" is to "detect any non-numbers" (i.e., any non-numeric character in a variable) - how is `is_numeric()` better than `ctype_digit()` for such case?!

Comment: @Matthieu Looking at this line in the question: "Need to make sure nothing weird gets put into my form fields" I'm assuming that the check needs to make sure there are **nothing but numeric characters** in a field, not make sure the content of a field could possibly evaluate to a number (ie 0x5)

Comment: @binaryLV well the second part of the question is "*Need to make sure nothing weird gets put into my form fields*", which is a classic problem. So i'm basing my answer mostly on the second part of the question bc I somehow feel that the OP just want to "make sure nothing weird gets put into his form fields" and is not especially looking after a specific case where he want's only numerical character. That's an interpretation of his needs, and maybe I am wrong.

Comment: @Marty Yes, you are right, though I feel that he's just expressing his need with a start of a [bad] solution (only numerical characters) whereas his need is only "to make sure nothing weird gets put into my form fields"

Comment: ctype_digit() it better if u wanna check from type data of string. if type data is integer or float just using is_int() or is_numerik()

Comment: it works fine in laravel 7

Answer (score 15):

This will return `true` if there are non-numbers in the string. It detects letters, spaces, tabs, new lines, whatever isn't numbers.

```
preg_match('#[^0-9]#',$variable)
```

Comment: Carefull, I may have misunderstood the question. This line will return `true` if `$variable` equals `4.2`. Is it what you need?

Comment: Why use regular expression when there are built in functions to do that.

Comment: @Matthieu Depends if you need "numbers" or "digits". As the question was precising that spaces were important, I assumed it was to check if there weren't anything else than DIGITS.

Comment: `[^0-9]` is more concisely written as `\D`

Answer (score 4):

This will check whether the input value is numeric or not. Hope this helps

```
if(!preg_match('#[^0-9]#',$value))
{
    echo "Value is numeric";
}
else
{
    echo "Value not numeric";
}
```

Comment: `[^0-9]` is more concisely written as `\D`

Answer (score 3):

This worked out to be ~30% faster than `preg_match` for my test cases, while still letting you match any characters you want:

```
if( $a !== '' && trim($a, ' 1234567890.,') === '' ){
   print("The variable contains only digits, decimal separators and spaces");
}
```

This simply removes all characters supplied from the string. If the result is an empty string, you know it only contained those characters.

Comment: [`trim()` allows ranged syntax via two dots](https://stackoverflow.com/q/72865138/2943403).

Answer (score 1):

PHP has the function [is_numeric()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.is-numeric.php) which may be what you are looking for.

Comment: See comments about `is_numeric()` below @Matthieu's answer.

Answer (score 1):

Cast and compare:

```
function string_contain_number($val)
{
     return ($val + 0 == $val) ? true : false;
}
```

Comment: (Assuming this approach always works) The ternary isn't necessary.  `return $val + 0 == $val;` will be the same.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you want only (and only) valid integers and you dont want users to mess up with your data and database with `hexadecimal` or `binary` or any other form of numbers then you can always use this method:

```
if(((string) (int) $stringVariable) === $stringVariable) {
    // Thats a valid integer :p
}
else {
    // you are out of luck :(
}
```

The trick is simple. It casts the variable of type string to integer type and then casts it back to string.
Super fast, Super simple.

For the sake of testing I've prepared a test:

```
'1337' is pure integer.
'0x539' is not.
'02471' is not.
'0000343' is not.
'0b10100111001' is not.
'1337e0' is not.
'not numeric' is not.
'not numeric 23' is not.
'9.1' is not.
'+655' is not.
'-586' is pure integer.
```

The only place that this method falls short is on negative numbers, so you need to check that beside this (use `((string) (int) $stringVariable) === $stringVariable && $stringVariable[0] !== "-"`).

Now I thought that the `preg_match` method is the best. but in any project that deals with users, speed is an important factor. so I prepared a benchmarking test doing that above test for 500,000 times and the results were amazing:

My own invented method took only:
`6.4700090885162`
seconds to complete as compared to `preg_match` which took:
`77.020107984543` seconds to complete this test!